# React-Router-dom and useHistory. Pushes new URL to history and changes URL but page does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am to create an app which utilizes react-router-dom. I am currently trying to us eversion 5.2.0. I have tried to isolate the issue and focused on just making the routing work but have not succeeded yet. I made the app using npx create-react-app.

**Package.json**

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { About, Contact, Home } from "./Components";


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={withRouter(Contact)}/>
        <Route exact path="/about">
          <About/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Components.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Links = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const buttonClicked = (link) => {
        history.push(link);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={() => buttonClicked('/')}>home</button>
            <button onClick={() => buttonClicked('/about')}>about</button>
            <button onClick={() => buttonClicked('/contact')}>contact</button>
        </>
    )
}

export const Contact = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Links/>
            Contact page
        </div>
    )
}

export const Home = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Links/>
            Home page
        </div>
    )
}

export const About = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Links/>
            About page
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried using withRouter in various places without success.
I have also changed how the Routes are written to include exact paths and non exact paths so am unsure what is causing the issue.

This is my current code. When a button is clicked, the URL changes accordingly. However, the component is not rendered again with the correct route. If you could help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you're using buttons for your routing. The documentation for [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) says that it can be used for routing via hooks, but I don't see anything to suggest that it can be used in combination with BrowserRouter. Others can feel free to correct me if this is incorrect.

Personally, I use the Link component and then style it as needed.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to="/path-you-want">Text For Link</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"; ... <Router> ...code </Router>`

try importing browserRouter as router

Answer (score 0):

i just did some googling i found that it's because
react-router-dom v5 doesnt compatible with React 18 StrictMode
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7870
so by removing Strictmode shoud be fix your problem

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  // <StrictMode>
    <App />
  // </StrictMode>
);
```

i also test it on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-darkness-35qzsy?file=/src/index.js

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@5` so `useHistory` is the correct hook. `useNavigate` is a RRDv6 hook that replaced `useHistory.

Comment: oh my bad, i didn't see the version

Answer (score 0):

You need to put exact on the "/" route rather than the other routes.